# Using carousel using a View component?

Tags: react-native

Im creating a carousel effect with example data that in which it shows other payments when I swipe left/right[image]

However the tutorials im seeing in how to create such effect are using exclusively Flatlist components and using its data  prop to display its data. The box in which im indicating (blue) is actually a View component with styles and text inside. How can I create a carousel effect using View components?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these packages:

1. [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel)
2. [react-native-swipe-gestures](https://github.com/glepur/react-native-swipe-gestures)